# How do i equaly distribute certain weights if i know how many times they appear

Tags: combinatorics

So i have those number groups

0, 273073
5, 222768
7, 43000
3, 24000
10, 12000
15, 12000
20, 12000
50, 1000
100, 100
500, 50
1000, 5
5000, 2
15000, 1
40000, 1

The first is the "weight"(which doesnt really matter in this calculation) and the second is how many times they appear (total 600,000). How do i distribute those numbers equaly according to how many times they appear so it would be something like this:

0 0 5 0 5 0 5 0 5 7 0 5 ... then i would assume at around position 300,000 would be 15000 and 40000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you'd like to distribute them discretely, it's impossible to do it perfectly. Nonetheless, we'll do our best. If we number the positions $1$ through $600000$, we can start with the easy ones:

At positions $300000$ and $300001$ we should have the weights $15000$ and $40000$ (since they're both equally common, it doesn't matter which weight is in which position).

At positions $200000$ and $399999$ we should have the two weights $5000$. Again, if we could distribute them continuously we could do $199999\frac{2}{3}$ and $399999\frac{1}{3}$, but instead we choose the nearest integers.

We can continue this process - for the $5$ objects of weight $1000$ we'd use

$$n\left[\frac{599999}{6}\right]$$

For $n=1,2,3,4,5$

---

This should generalize easily to the other weight amounts.

Comment: so for every object i use x(599999/(n+1))? where n is the count of the object and x is 1...n

Comment: @Vajura yes, but sometimes they will overlap

Comment: yea i add +1 until i get the next free spot if they overlap

Comment: hm i might actualy need a difrent approach where i need to get a field big enough so that they dont overlap and then remove the places that are empty